# service is interrupted on the background even if startForegroundService and startForeground are added

Tags: android, service, background

Masters:
There is problem on my program as following:
Compile platform：android studio 3.2
moible of test: android 8.0
operation: press "home", make progrem run on the background. it is OK on charging state. If not charged, the service would be "dead" after about one minute. How can I make it keep alive longer? Thanks. codes attached:

========the first part：activity class （partial codes）

```
Intent i=new  Intent(this,RegistService.class); 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   this.startForegroundService(i);
} else {
   this.startService(i);
}
```

========the 2nd part:  service class

```
public class RegistService extends Service {
    Timer timer;
    int num=0;
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID_STRING = "test001";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_STRING, "test001", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID_STRING).build();
            startForeground(28, notification);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                num=num+1;
                Log.v(num+"count","test");
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000,1000);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on a Xiaomi or Huawei device? It sounds like a battery management app is killing your process.

Comment: I tested on Huawei mate 9.   you means that  there is no problem except for Huaiwei and Xiaomi?  there is battery management, I have flagged all the option.  But problem still existed.  Do you any other solution？